# Merge two select <value> into a single statment?

Tags: sql, mysql

My main problem is i dont know how to say select 1 on this cond select 2 on that cond. So i made them both their own statement. Is there a way to combine them?

```
select 1 from FlagContent where user=? and rev = ?;
select 2 from ContentRevision r
            join ContentRevision r2 on r.content=r2.content
            join FlagContent fc on fc.user=? and fc.rev = r2.id
            where r.id=?;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`UNION`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx) to "merge" similar result sets.

> SQL UNION allows you to combine two or more than two result set from multiple tables together.

However, there are some conditions to using it:

- The number of columns in each SELECT statement has to be the same
- The data type of the column in the column list of the SELECT statement must be the same or at least convertible.

---

```
select 1 from FlagContent where user=? and rev = ?;
UNION ALL
select 2 from ContentRevision r
            join ContentRevision r2 on r.content=r2.content
            join FlagContent fc on fc.user=? and fc.rev = r2.id
            where r.id=?;
```

Comment: Note that UNION ALL is faster as it doesn't attempt to remove duplicates. Removing duplicates requires sorting and comparing which can be expensive.

Comment: @acidzombie24 - They will each be on a different row. `ExecuteScalar` will not work.